# Google Drive API Connection Refused

Tags: centos, google-drive, api

I have a problem regarding uploading to Google Drive via the API.

I have 5 servers,

- server 1-3 on digital ocean = successful upload
- server 4 & 5 on local = failed upload

I get this error message:

> An error occurred uploading the document: Post https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?alt=json&convert=false&uploadType=resumable: dial tcp 36.86.63.182:443: connection refused

I tried:

- settings to open ports on firewall servers 4 & 5
- turn off firewall on servers 4 & 5
- setting to open the firewall port/filter on the router
- turning off the firewall on the router
- setting port fowarding on the modem
- upload to google drive from localhost (laptop with the same operating system & settings on servers 4 & 5) to the same destination as on servers 4 & 5 and be successful.

My assumption:

- Error does not come from the router, because local notebooks using centos 7 also with the same network can successfully upload
- Error also does not originate from the server, because it was tested on localhost successfully uploaded & has been tried to turn off the firewall on servers 4 & 5.

I used this reference to instal GDrive: https://www.mynotepaper.com/install-google-drive-and-schedule-backup-to-gdrive-on-centos-7.html

This is the script that I used https://gitlab.com/snippets/1903649.

I use Centos 7 operating system.

Answer (score 2):

GDrive is not being actively maintained at the moment.

You can use GDrive with your own credentials. To use your own credentials, you need to compile the project. These steps you have to follow to compile with your own OAuth credentials:

1. Install Go on Your Machine
2. Create own Google credentials & enable Google Drive API
3. Download [Gdrive](https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive), extract it
4. Open `handlers_drive.go` file and set your own credentials at lines 17 & 18
5. Then build the project and upload the compiled `gdrive` to your server

That's it. Now you're able to use `gdrive` as usual.

These steps are explained in this article: [Mount Google Drive using GDrive on Linux Server with Own OAuth Credentials](https://www.mynotepaper.com/mount-google-drive-using-gdrive-on-linux-server-with-own-oauth-credentials). You may take a look.